# How to convert a list of arrays into a nicely packaged state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API call returning a list of breweries. I want to convert it from its current format into my React state container. Something like:

```
state = {
    breweries: [ {name: Foo,
                  long: 45,
                  lat: -39.239},
                 {name: Bar,
                  long: 47,
                  lat: -27.394}
    ]
}
```

I've managed to get it into an array of Javascript objects (I think?) in my console.log. See the pic below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQiSu.jpg

I think I have to do something with the .map() function but I'm not sure what. Currently my code reads as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        breweries: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const breweries = axios
            .get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(list => this.setState({ breweries: list }));
    }

    printState = () => {
        console.log(this.state.breweries);
    };

    render() {
        const response = axios
            .get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
            .then(response => console.log(response));

        return (
            <div className="App">
                {/* <button onClick={this.printBreweries}>Click Me</button> */}
                <button onClick={this.printState}>Also click me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Currently the best I can do is shown in the code above. ".then(list => this.setState({ breweries: list }))" causes console.log(this.state.breweries) to output the array of objects, but it's not quite what I want.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will help you transform each item in the list e.g.

```
axios
  .get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
  .then(res => res.data.map(({ name, long, lat }) => ({ name, long, lat })))
  .then(list => this.setState({ breweries: list }));
```

*Note - the first `then` is making use of parameter [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [object initializer shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and leveraging arrow functions ability to return a default result by parenthesising the body, in this case an object literal is being returned*

Comment: Note I had to rewrite "long, lat" to match "longitude, latitude" as the ```res``` object contained those variable names instead of "long, lat". Just wanted to add this as I was getting "undefined" before I made the change.

Comment: @RolyPoly no worries, I was only going based on the properties you used in your example